# How to add multiple models to a JView?

Tags: component

I try to save data in multiple table from one view in joomla but two tables field names are same. So that's create error.
please guide me step by step.

Comment: You're going to have to provide some more details to get a good answer on this. What code are you using? What are the table names? What are the field names?

Answer (score 2):

You may try to do this in your view

```
$othermodel = JModelLegacy::getInstance('othermodel ','yourcomponentModel');
$othermodel->otherModelFunction();
```